# how to locate textarea element in selenium?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to locate textarea field using selenium. But not able to do so.

I tried below things :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//textarea[@id='inviteColleaguesArea']")).sendKeys("abc@test.coom");
WebElement element=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"inviteColleaguesArea\"]"));
element.clear();
element.sendKeys("abc@test.com");

driver.findElement(By.id("inviteColleaguesArea")).sendKeys("abc@test.com");
```

HTML -

```
<textarea placeholder="Enter email ids here separated by comma e.g. abc@xyz.com, klm@xyz.com" tabindex="1" id="inviteColleaguesArea" class="text contactFormFont ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" ng-model="inviteColleagues" style=" height:9%; width:100%;resize:none;margin-top: 5px;min-height:60px;" ng-keyup="checkForEmail($event,'inviteColleaguesArea','inviteColleagues');" ng-disabled="disableButtons" autofocus="" aria-invalid="false"></textarea>
```

Comment: Please share the reference HTML code or link

Comment: <textarea placeholder="Enter email ids here separated by comma e.g. abc@xyz.com, klm@xyz.com" tabindex="1" id="inviteColleaguesArea" class="text contactFormFont ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" ng-model="inviteColleagues" style=" height:9%; width:100%;resize:none;margin-top: 5px;min-height:60px;" ng-keyup="checkForEmail($event,'inviteColleaguesArea','inviteColleagues');" ng-disabled="disableButtons" autofocus="" aria-invalid="false"></textarea>

Comment: Please add what error is shown in the console.

Answer (score 0):

Use Find element by ID

```
driver.findElement(By.id("inviteColleaguesArea")).sendKeys("Test");
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But I tried that also but still error is coming.